# Displayed language does not match what keyboard types

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have 2 languages installed: EN (us) and LT. For some reason they flipped, and now LT types EN characters, and visa versa.

Is there anything I could do to reverse this? I'v tried removing LT, and adding it back, but it had no effect, as EN still was wrong.

Using 20.04.1 LTS + GNOME Shell 3.36.4

Comment: A language-setting has no relationship with the layout of your keyboard. Please check which layout is being used.

Comment: You could try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. Good luck!